# MacVim on Yosemite: Shift-Space

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, osx-yosemite

Never having thought about it, I just found out that I am used to Shift-Space doing the same thing as Space. But now it doesn't any more: my typing started looking like this a couple of days ago:

```
a[x +1]= b
```

where I wanted to write

```
a[x + 1] = b
```

I suppose I let go of Shift too slowly. It never used to be a problem, until I installed Yosemite, and now Shift-Space does not register at all any more. I tried `:imap <S-Space> <Space>`, but that too does not trigger.

It does not happen in Terminal Vim, nor does it happen in any other application I own.

EDIT: I am on a Japanese keyboard, using Kotoeri (Apple's Japanese IME).

Comment: I don’t expect so, but is Shift+Space bound to a new shortcut in Yosemite? Look in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and see if any of them have “⇧Space” as their shortcut. Also consider if you upgraded any third-party software that provides global keyboard shortcuts along with Yosemite – maybe as well as adding Yosemite compatibility, the upgrade added a new keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: Looked, and that's not it, and thanks for thinking with me. However, I seem to have (partially) solved it, thanks to the nice folks over at the [vim_mac mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_mac/Yo2DaV103rM). I'll edit the question and add an answer in case anyone else has the same problem and stumbles onto this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an incompatibility introduced in Yosemite's Kotoeri (Japanese IME). For the time being, switching to Google Japanese IME as an alternative (or not using Japanese input in the first place, if that is an option) circumvents the issue. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_mac/Yo2DaV103rM) for details.